# Antiderivative involving the exponential function

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> Integrate $$\int e^{x+e^{x+e^{x}}} \mathrm{d}x$$

This is a question from the book I am reading, no solution or an answer is provided.
I am learning integration from a book by myself so let me know if I did anything incorrectly. I have searched for this integral with approach0 and SearchOnMath but nothing relevant came up.

So far here is what I did -

$$\int e^{x+e^{x+e^{x}}} \mathrm{d}x \implies \int e^x e^{e^xe^{e^x}} \mathrm{d}x$$

Substituting $u = e^x \implies \mathrm{d}u = e^x$

$$\therefore \int {u e^{ue^u} \over u} \mathrm{d}u \implies \int { e^{ue^u}} \mathrm{d}u $$

But I am not sure how to proceed or if all this is even correct. Any hints will do.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you can continue this one step further, with $v = e^u$? However that leads to $\int e^{v\ln v}\frac{dv}{v} = \int v^{v - 1} dv$ which I doubt has an elementary solution

Comment: This integral has no closed form in terms of  elementary functions.

Comment: @markvs Hence do I leave the problem as it remains perhaps ? I mean to say that this exercise is right after the first chapter (up-til Integration by substitution is covered) so I had my doubts that it would have a proper solution.

Comment: I think you have done all one could about this problem.